# php preg_match_all Not getting all results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am using php `preg_match_all` to extract some parts of a message like this:

```
$customerMessage = '"message":"success:2,2;3,3;"' ;
preg_match_all('/("message":")([a-z0-9A-Z]+):([0-9]+,[0-9]+;)+/', $customerMessage, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
die;
```

this code output is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) ""message":"success:2,2;3,3;"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) ""message":""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "success"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "3,3;"
  }
}
```

Why cant I get part `2,2;` ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get the last match of a group. Two get all values like `x,x;` you can use your current regex, changed a bit:

```
preg_match_all('/("message":")([a-z0-9A-Z]+):(.*)"/', $customerMessage, $matches);
/* $matches[3] --> 2,2;3,3;
```

Now you can get group 3 with `$matches[3]` and match all `x,x;` with `[0-9]+,[0-9]+;`

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+,[0-9]+/', $matches[3], $matches2);
/* $matches[0] --> 2,2;
/* $matches[1] --> 3,3;
```

Comment: You can only get the last match of a group! Thanks. You are right!